# I'm Getting an error "Endpoint Error: MethodNotAllowed" in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, paysimple

Everytime I'm going to this view I'm getting this error in fetching the list of customer from the sandbox ap. I'm using PaysimpleSDK https://github.com/PaySimple/PaySimpleSDK/wiki/Customer-Service

My error

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: PaySimpleSdk.Exceptions.PaySimpleEndpointException: Endpoint Error: MethodNotAllowed:
>
> var customers = await customerService.GetCustomersAsync(CustomerSort.FirstName);

here is my controller

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> Trial()
    {
        string username = "myusername";
        string apiKey = "apikey";
        string baseUrl = "https://sandbox-api.paysimple.com/v4/customer";
        var settings = new PaySimpleSettings( apiKey, username, baseUrl );
        

        var customerService = new CustomerService(settings);
        var customers = await customerService.GetCustomersAsync();

        return View(customers.ToString());
    }
```

my view (I can't copy the whole view code,because it have a table)

```
@model IEnumerable<PaySimpleSdk.Customers.Customer>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

 @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
```

Comment: If you debug, the error occurs in this line: `customerService.GetCustomersAsync();` or it doesn't even enter `Trial()` action? Or somewhere else?

Comment: It seems you are calling a method with a http verb(post, put, get...) is not the one the method expects

Comment: @Alisson the errors occur, when I'm entering the Trial

Comment: @GhiniAntonio I don't have a http verb

Comment: This exception is comming from their library, so we can't help at all. Take a look in [their documentation](https://github.com/PaySimple/PaySimpleSDK/wiki/Exceptions) about this `PaySimpleEndpointException` you are getting.

Comment: It's say "PaySimpleEndpointException are thrown when the PaySimple API returns a non successful HTTP Status Code." so is there any wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

In mvc i usually get this error when i call the action with http get and the action has been declared to serve only http post or in general when you have action declared for specific verb and you try to get it with the ones not allowed

Comment: I don't have a HTTP verb, but I think it is a get, because of the ".GetCustomersAsync" it is in the PaySimpleSDK

Comment: https://github.com/PaySimple/PaySimpleSDK/wiki/Customer-Service I'm just copying the code in here